# Lighting-Record-Edit-Form - Set Record-Id

Tags: lightning-web-components

On my lighting-record-edit form, I want to set the record-id to that of a newly saved opportunity.  With the help of this site, I now can retrieve the id of the saved record.  However, I have an issue setting the variable used for the forms record-id.  My code is below. I can see that event.detail.id is returning the new opportunity id, however, when I try to set 'this.selectedOppId = event.detail.id;' I get an error, 'Cannot Read property value of undefined'  I'm really confused.  The record does get created and the ID appears to update but I get the error.  I appreciate any help. Thanks!!!!

Here is error that displays in the console:  here is error {"message":"Cannot read property 'value' of undefined","detail":"","output":{}}

//form:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={selectedOppId} 
        object-api-name="Opportunity" record-type-id={recordTypeId}
        onsuccess={onSuccess} onsubmit ={onSubmit} onerror={handleError}>
```

//Javascript

```
@track selectedOppId;
onSuccess(event){
    this.loading = false ;
    this.oppid = event.detail.id;
        console.log(' !!!! ' + event.detail.id);
    this.accid = event.detail.fields.AccountId.value; 
 
     //display tabs
     this.showrelated = true;
        //this line throws a 'Cannot Read property value of undefined'
     this.selectedOppId = event.detail.id;
        console.log('selectedOppId ' + this.selectedOppId);
     
    this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Opportunity Updated',
        message:  'You have updated the Opportunity',
        variant: 'success'
    })); 
}
```

Comment: Can you try rendering form conditionally like `<template if:true={selectedOppId}><<lightning-record-edit-form...></template>` ?

Comment: Also you might need to check if event and detail is not null `if(event && event.detail && event.detail.id) { //assign this.selectedOppId and show toast }`

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I wrapped the entire method in the if statement but still getting the error.  I added the error I get in console to the question.  thanks!!

Comment: Try Chromes “pause on exception” to trace where it fails exactly. Note you’ve got a space after onsubmit and do you have recordtype value?

Comment: thank you I will try the pause on exception.  I do have a recordtype value.

Comment: dzh, that was perfect, I now know that cause.  The error is on a lookup to user field.  I must be missing something needed for a lookup field.  The error is hard for me to translate but among the text is object.computeRecordPills  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to set the record-id after record creation in lightning-record-edit-form.

[image]

**html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={selectedOppId} onsuccess={onSuccess} object-api-name="Contact">
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Id">
        </lightning-output-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Email">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button
            class="slds-m-top_small"
            variant="brand"
            type="submit"
            name="update"
            label="Update">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>        
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class ParentLightningWebComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedOppId;
    accid = '';
    onSuccess(event){
        //this line throws a 'Cannot Read property value of undefined'
        this.selectedOppId = event.detail.id;
        console.log('selectedOppId ' + this.selectedOppId);

        this.accid = event.detail.fields.AccountId.value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sanket.  I can update the id also but I am getting the error, 'Cannot Read property value of undefined'  Just can't figure out why the error.  thanks!